# How to successfully download Metpy on Spyder?

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, environment, metpy

I'm new to Python so please bear with me (I learned 5 days ago).

I've been working on a SkewT diagram using Matplotlib, Metpy, Pandas, and a few others. Whenever I attempt to import metpy,it isn't recognized as a module. Previously when I was working in Thonny I never got an error message in reference to Metpy, but once again Python would crush upon plotting my graph which may mean the issue was there even then.

I imported the path to my path manager AND my code and it resulted in an error message, essentially saying this path can't be used (despite getting it directly from terminal). I then created an environment and imported Metpy (which worked fine) and switched to that environment through Spyder. Now when I open Spyder it says "An error ocurred while starting the kernel" and that I must download Spyder-kernel to my environment. Of course I then did that and restarted Spyder. The same error message persists. I think I might have seen something on Stack overflow that led me to believe that there's a chance Spyder and Metpy are completely incompatible, but I want to know that for sure before switching to a different IDE.

I'm going to lose my mind I think. I also am in touch with a fairly skilled Python coder and he can't figure it out either.

Comment: I am personally able to use metpy with spyder with Python 3.18.13, so they're definitely able to be used together. If it isn't too much trouble you can always try reinstalling spyder and your modules with Anaconda.

Comment: There's nothing unique about MetPy that should make it incompatible with Spyder. It  relies upon: Numpy, Matplotlib, Scipy, xarray, pandas, pyproj (as well as using pint, pooch, and optionally cartopy). Are you able to use those other libraries without error?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Sorry to hear that you're having so much troubles trying to use Metpy with Spyder. Since you can't connect Spyder to the environment in which you installed Metpy, the simplest thing you can do is to install Spyder on it as well. That should work without problems.